# What is the correct way to read advertisement packets from a BLE sensor using bluez 5.43 and DBus

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I am trying to implement a C++ code (using bluez 5.43 and dbus) to read advertisement packets from a BLE sensor. As per the bluez DBus docs, there is a **StartDiscovery** API that can be used to scan for nearby devices. However, I am unable to find any APIs to store/parse the advertisement packets from nearby BLE devices. The [advertising-api.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt) lists registeradvertisement API but as per my understanding, it can be used only for creating advertisement packets and not reading from an external device (or am I wrong?) Can someone please guide me on the correct way to get advertisement packets from nearby BLE devices using bluez and DBus?

Comment: As I understand, you do `StartDiscovery`, then the `Device` objects appear as they are being discovered. The properties of these objects are probably filled with data from the advertisement packets.

Comment: @Velkan: thanks for responding. To be honest, I'm a little confused here. I have a BLE sensor that transmits sensor readings regularly in the form of advertising packets. This information is contained in the low energy scan response as well. So I need the full response to parse required data. I'm trying to implement this using dbus and bluez-5.43. I don't think any properties give low energy scan response. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: org.bluez.Device1 has ServiceData and ManufacturerData. Isn't they are the same as ServiceData and ManufacturerData from the advertising-api.txt? Maybe they contain AdvData that carries the readings?

Comment: I tried reading the manufacturer data but the values remain the same even when temperature is changed. The sensor has an open source Android app. When I checked the source code, it seems the app is reading the complete low energy scan response and parsing the necessary fields. The temperature variations are being correctly shown in the app. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do the values in ManufacturerData contain at least one correct reading?

Comment: The initial readings are correct. The problem is when I vary the temperature, it is not being correctly updated in the manufacturer data. In the case of android, the changes are reflected instantaneously. But android has its own APIs for LE scan of course. In my case, the manufacturer data values get updated only after I power off and then power on the sensor.

Comment: There was a similar problem a long time ago. I've googled a [conversation on the mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg61789.html) and a [patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg61918.html) that was applied, so it should work in the current version. I'd find the commit that introduced that patch (it's more pleasant to look at an actual commit than the bits of the patch in the mailing list), rebuild bluez from source and insert some `printf`s around that place in the source code.

Comment: Oh. alright. I will try with the patch and report back. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I checked the bluez-5.43 source code and the patch is integrated. I am using Intel's tinyb library's get_manufacturer_data API (https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/blob/6e580f494ced312ed8f56bcd3fc33499d91720e3/src/BluetoothDevice.cpp) to get the manufacturer data. I am not sure if the library caches data internally.

Comment: Please excuse me. I just realized that my previous comment was a little stupid. What I meant to say was tinyb library might be using an older version of bluez, where the patch hasn't been implemented. Can you please suggest any other C/C++ dbus wrapper library other than tinyb?

Comment: In tinyb I've googled a commit about [Add notifications for manufacturer data, service data and services](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/commit/52a0b0660e84560822768aa78061f8eb3cab4889), so it's supposed to forward that information. I've never programmed bluetooth, can't suggest anything.

Comment: It seems the issue is not the library. I feel that the manufacturer data caching has not been fully fixed yet (I could be wrong). I was able to fetch the manufacturer data using `dbus-send` command and it always returns the same value. Even when I power off the sensor and use the command, the same inital values are displayed, instead of throwing some error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I was finally able to get the manufacturer data by using Intel's tinyb library. It has an enable_manufacturer_data_notifications API which enables you to be notified whenever the manufacturer data changes.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you described in one your last comment is the right one (the advertising data is not beeing updated) : if I am correct a BLE device is not supposed to be up all the time, it can sleep or turn to low-power etc.

In this context, it is not weird that the data is in some way "cached". From my experience, when you perform a scan and discover a device (even if you don't Connect to it), the device information will be stored for some time.

In your case, that's problematic because you are passing data through the advertising. However *there is a way to force bluez to remove all it's cached data about a device* : 
the adapter-api provides a  **RemoveDevice(object device)** method. It takes the object path (eg "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_AA_BB_AA_BB_AA") as argument.

If you're looking for DBus bindings in C, I suggest GLib GDBus (you will find links at the bottom of this tutorial on freedesktop website : https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html).

If you are familiar with **bluetoothctl** (a tool to interact with bluez using commands), it was developped by the bluez guys using Glib GDbus and you can find the source code here (look at the bottom to find the command list) : https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client/main.c

There are more straigthforward ways to use GDBus with bluez but bluetoothctl source code is a start and you'll find examples for pretty much anything that is possible to do with bluez =)